# How do I distinguish between an ID and a display value in a WPF ItemSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a data collection that I'd like to display in a WPF DataGrid (in C#). Setting the ItemSource property of the DataGrid works great. The control grabs values, places them in columns and generally just works. The problem is that some of the attributes in the displayed object are IDs. For editing, that's fine, but for displaying them on screen I want to return the string to which they correspond.

In other words, instead of:

[image: Box with IDs]

I want:

[image]

In Qt, there's a concept of "role" for the ::data() method. How do I hand the appropriate "version" of a particular field to the DataGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to convert 'Box type' integer to string like this:

```
class BoxTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly List<string> idNames = new List<string>()
    {
        "Flat-rate (small)",
        "Flat-rate (medium)",
        "Flat-rate (large)",
        "Regional A",
        "Regional B",
        "Regional C"
    };

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var index = (int)value - 1;

        return index >= 0 && index < idNames.Count ? idNames[index] : value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var idName = (string)value;
        var index = idNames.IndexOf(idName);

        return index >= 0 ? index + 1 : int.Parse(idName, culture);
    }
}
```

And hook it up into DataGrid like this:

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

**C# behind XAML**

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "BoxType")
    {
        var column = (DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column;
        var binding = (Binding)column.Binding;
        binding.Converter = new BoxTypeConverter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this by using a combobox in the left column. An example is like following :

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Comms.View}" RowHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowTemplate}"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFC9CACA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFC9CACA" RowHeaderWidth="50" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="CommTypeComboBoxColumn" Header="Type" 
                                    SelectedValuePath="CommTypeId" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CommTypeId}">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=CommTypes.View}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=CommTypes.View}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Waarde" Binding="{Binding CommValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I hope you understand about binding otherwise you will need more help.

Answer (score 0):

If the text for box types are static values (not read from db) you can use a simple data trigger to customize each row like this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Box Type">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="UNKNOWN TYPE" x:Name="text"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="1">
                        <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="TYPE 1"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="2">
                        <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="TYPE 2"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="3">
                        <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="TYPE 3"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding Count}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

*note that TargetName="text" refers to name of TextBlock, Property="Text" refers to its Text.*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that, but yes, the values are from a DB.